# Cannot drop procedure with weird names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In MySQL, I cannot drop procedure **mobisys_mtly_db`cms_partner_add_or_edit** because it has symbol **`**.

Detailed example in console

```
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE mobisys_mtly_db`cms_partner_add_or_edit;
`> `
-> ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`cms_partner_add_or_edit;` ' at line 1

```
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE "mobisys_mtly_db\`cms_partner_add_or_edit";
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"mobisys_mtly_db`cms_partner_add_or_edit"' at line 1

The following do not work:

> DROP PROCEDURE mobisys_mtly_db`cms_partner_add_or_edit
>
> DROP PROCEDURE mobisys_mtly_db\`cms_partner_add_or_edit
>
> DROP PROCEDURE 'mobisys_mtly_db`cms_partner_add_or_edit'
>
> DROP PROCEDURE 'mobisys_mtly_db\`cms_partner_add_or_edit'
>
> DROP PROCEDURE "mobisys_mtly_db`cms_partner_add_or_edit"
>
> DROP PROCEDURE "mobisys_mtly_db\`cms_partner_add_or_edit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this query -

```
DROP PROCEDURE `mobisys_mtly_db``cms_partner_add_or_edit`
```

Documentation page - [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html).